# Is it possible to have the label of an nglAccordionSection accordion as a component or html element instead of just text?

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-lightning

I want to create a nesting table in Angular using Ng-lightning. I'm trying to do that by adding tables inside of an accordion.

However, I can't seem to find a way to set the label of the nglAccordionSection as a component or element instead of just text.

Other solutions besides adding tables to accordions are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the "**Custom reusable header**" example at http://ng-lightning.github.io/ng-lightning/#/components/accordion. There you can see that you can use ng-template as value of the `[label]`.

For example:

```
<ng-template #header>html header</ng-template>
<ul ngl-accordion [(activeName)]="active">
  <ng-template nglAccordionSection name="A" [label]="header">Content area</ng-template>
</ul>
```